# How using class func to call a method from another class in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uibutton, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

I would to call from the GameViewController my timer method (written in my GameScene) in order to pause the game with an UIButton initialized in GameViewController class.

I'm trying to use a `class func` like this :

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        GameScene.startTimer()
    }

    class func startTimer(){
        timerCount = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0
        , target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func updateTimer(dt:NSTimer){

        counter--
        counterGame++

        if counter<0{
            timerCount.invalidate()
            removeCountDownTimerView()
        } else{
            labelCounter.text = "\(counter)"
        }

        if counterGame>20{
            balloon.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
        }
        if counterGame>40{
            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.8)
        }
        if counterGame>60{
            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -1)
        }
    }

    func removeCountDownTimerView(){
        defaults.setInteger(balloonDestroyed, forKey: "score")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let settingController: UIViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverViewController") as UIViewController
        let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
        vc?.presentViewController(settingController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}
```

But this code return an error :

`[Funfair_balloon.GameScene updateTimer:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b13d940`

When I don't use the `class func` the app works perfectly but I can't stop the timer with my UIButton. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: In your `class func startTimer` you tell the timer to call `updateTimer` in `timerCount = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` but `self` in a class func is NOT an instance, and so you can't use it to call your `updateTimer`, which is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I replace self by GameScene(). I don't have the error anymore but the timer is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when using `class func`, you cannot use the variables that were initialized in that class.

So for example, you cannot use the variable `timerCount` if it was initialized in the class `GameScene`.

Comment: So I have to initialized all variables I need in the `class func` out of the `GameScene class`?

Comment: Either that or you pass them in your func as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use class functions. The following should work using just the current instance of `GameScene`. Note that the `var timerCount` is an optional (since you can't easily override the `init`) until such times as you create it in `startTimer()`, and so you will have to unwrap it when you eventually invalidate it.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var timerCount: NSTimer? = nil
    var counter = 100 // or whatever

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.startTimer()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        self.timerCount = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0
            , target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func updateTimer(dt: NSTimer) {
        // Do stuff
        counter--

        if counter < 0 {
            self.timerCount!.invalidate() // or dt.invalidate()
            self.removeCountDownTimerView()
        } else {
            // update counter label
        }
        // Do more stuff

    }

    func removeCountDownTimerView() {
        // Do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have my GameScene where the game and the timer are written. In my GameViewController I created the "pause" UIButton. When I tap on the pause button I want to stop the game AND the timer. For the moment I can pause the skView (not the scene) and invalidate `timerCount` with this button but the nodes continue to be created and I can't start again the timer. That's why I want to access the methods present in GameScene from the ViewController.

Comment: Well I just tried your code. It works but how can I restart the timer from the ViewController with the `pauseButton`?

Comment: Make the `startTimer` an action, and connect it to your button?

Comment: Ok I Will try that. (I'm still a noob) :-D